# Writing foo with nested structs

Tags: struct, solidity

I am writing a function that adds an element to a list of structs, where each element has a nested struct inside.

I know it is NOT the most efficient way to do so, but enough for a PoC.
In any case, my code consists of:

```
external[] mylist;

struct external {
  string id;
  string name1:
  internal[] internalList;
};

struct internal {
  string name2;
  uint256 amount;
}

function addElement(string memory _id,
                    string memory _name1,
                    string memory _name2,
                    uint256 _amount ) public restricted{
   internal memory intl = internal(_name2, _amount);
   myList.push(external(_id, _name1, intl);
}
```

You can forget about the restricted modifier;

The error I am getting here is on the 'intl' struct and it says:

> Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from struct Contract_Name.internal memory to struct Contract_Name.internal memory[] memory requested.

So I assume it is pretty obvious, but I have no clue of how to fix it and make it work.

Please help